# Triggering a click with jQuery Mobile on pageinit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, eventtrigger

I am attempting to trigger a click on a specific `<li>` on my page with jQuery Mobile on the `pageinit` event.

I can successfully trigger the click, however I get an error on the line:

`var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage;`

> Error: TypeError: currentPage is undefined

What I am trying to achieve is that if a parameter of `reminder` is passed through in the URL then I want to trigger a click on a `<li>`. I'm not sure if i'm using the wrong jQM event (pageinit), but for some reason there appears to be no "active page".

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function (event, ui) {

    var page = $(event.target);

    page.find("li.static_nav").on('click', function () {
        var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage;
        var subheader = currentPage.find("#static_page_sub_header");
        var target = $(this).attr("data-target");

        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active').find('a').clone(true, true).appendTo(subheader.empty());

        currentPage.find(".static_panel").hide();

        return false;
    });


    if (page.find('#p_content').length !== 0) {
        var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(document.location.href);
        var query_string = url.search;
        if (/reminder/i.test(query_string)) {
            $('li.static_nav:eq(1)', $.mobile.activePage).trigger('click');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: pageinit is only fired once, the first time the page is loaded.  If the page is already in the cache (already been loaded) then this event is not fired when returning to the page.   The pageshow event is fired everytime the page is displayed regardless of new or cached

Comment: I would try moving the if statement portion of your code above into a pageshow event but leave the click binding in pageinit

Comment: @Drew Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for. Oddly, I haven't had the need to add any of my application logic into the `pageshow` event in my code as yet (although I did have a placeholder for it). I'm more than happy to accept this as the answer if you wish to submit, however is there another way to doing this _without_ utilising the `pageshow` jQM event?

Comment: There are a 6 different events that are triggered in a JQM cached or new page load starting with pagebeforechange and ending with pagechange (13 events for the very first page loaded and 12 events for a new page).  However, (IMHO) I think how and where you are currently looking is the right place.

Comment: Just curious,  why are you hesitant to use the pageshow event?

Comment: @Drew I've got no problem with using it, and I am doing exactly that now, however I was slightly hesitant in using it as I had managed to build and maintain my application without using the event up until now. Happy to accept an answer from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the following code out of the pageinit event and into a pageshow event:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {

var page = $(event.target);

if (page.find('#p_content').length !== 0) {
    var url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(document.location.href);
    var query_string = url.search;
    if (/reminder/i.test(query_string)) {
        $('li.static_nav:eq(1)', $.mobile.activePage).trigger('click');
    }
}

});
```